# Mongoose: How to get back all docs that its flag value is true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb to store all my "post" within my website.
I would like to find all documents that are "public"

My idea is to make a flag inside each document to indicate whether the post is public or private ... But I am not sure if this is a good approach for this in mongo

This is the scheme of my Doc. It represents a "Post". In its "public" field, this reflects whether it is public or not

This is the example:
[image]

I would like to filter it in server-side. So, I handle this by mongoose.

But I am not sure if this approach or schema design for public/private is efficient or not.

Here is my idea to do it:

```
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
 Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId(userId) }
      },
      {
        $match: { public: true }
      }

    ])
      .then((posts) => res.send(posts))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(400);
      });
```

It seems so strange and inefficient, so I would like to ask for a comment or improvement for the code above

Comment: How do you use private and public. If all the use cases are separate, keep separate collections

Comment: My idea is to make flag inside each docment to indicate whether it is public or private post... But I am not sure if this is a good approach for this in mongo

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.find({public: true}).then(result => {console.log(result)})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Its ok to have public flag to indicate whether post is public or private.
You can try the following code to return all public documents.

```
Post.find({ public: true })
.then((posts) => res.send(posts))
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(400);
});
```

Comment: Hi May I know that if there will be a performance issue ; For example, post search is allowed within my app. So I may index all keywords first. Then I do my post.find({content : keywords}) in my first search. But then how do I do the filter like what you did in the beginning?

Comment: Just add another property to the filter query..
Post.find({ content: keywords, public: true })
.then((posts) => res.send(posts))
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(400);
});

Comment: Indexes are special data structures that store a small portion of collection's data set in an easy to traverse form. Index can improve efficiency of read operation but comes with a performance cost. Consider the relative frequency of each query in the application and whether the query justifies an index.